# Retrieving antivirus info

Tags: c#, wmi, antivirus

How can I pull the name of the installed anti virus from WSC and if the virus database is updated or needs updating?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Surely the Antivirus software has a responsibility to know when it requires updating and has a job to do so...it is a job that is not suited for C# code to just do that...

Answer (score 1):

the solution is to query the `win32_antivirusproduct` for information about the status of the installed antivirus. in fact there is a detailed article about the subject that will help you. it is in vb.net but you can simply translate the few lines.

<strike>[Detect Installed Antivirus using System.Management](http://www.developersource.net/DevPage.aspx?ID=4)</strike>

Updated link: [Detect installed Antivirus from code](http://alitarhini.wordpress.com/2010/10/31/detect-installed-antivirus-from-code/)

Comment: That won't work for vista+ I had similar code for c# and even tried it in vb.net. I believe after vista sp1 AV's no longer write to root\SecurityCenter

Comment: check your security settings. i have vista on my desktop and it works perfectly

Comment: @Omega, you're right - Windows Vista SP1 has a new API for Security Center. You need to use the root\SecurityCenter2 namespace instead. Check out these links: http://blogs.msdn.com/alejacma/archive/2008/05/12/how-to-get-antivirus-information-with-wmi-vbscript.aspx http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/Forefrontclientgeneral/thread/80527cd5-5acd-414e-96fd-a21578b362a2